# WP File Manager - Changes Not Reflected In Site

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I am a JavaScript developer now working with WordPress/WooCommerce as a data manager. Only tech guy on site. Anyways, we have a folder for brand images that I can access through WP File Manager. I uploaded a new image by over writing the old one. A brand we sell changed their logo. I thought the change would be reflected once our caching updated. Other changes did update and I have access to when our search service cache updates. No changes. Now I don't yet have access to the actual server - only the WP Dashboard. My question is what needs to happen before this change occurs? Normally I would be using git and have full access to my linux server but that really isnt my role here. Just curious how WP File Manager works. Thanks.

Comment: Going to ask the dumb question here as you didn't mention it: did you clear/hard-refresh your browser's cache after you replaced the image?

Comment: @cabrerahector yup, not dumb, always try most obvious first right? Especially, since I am not familiar with this system.

Comment: If you cleared your browser's cache and you still see the old image, is the site perhaps using a CDN service? (eg. Cloudflare) If so, you may need to clear the CDN's cache as well so it picks up the updated image. If the answer is no, you may want to share your site's URL (and the URL of the updated image) so we can have a look.

Comment: Yes we have cloudflare caching. There is a plugin but i don't seem to have access to any options/account dashboard. We also have a search results caching service, but I do have access to refreshing/re-indexing the site with that one.